# firefox + html5 + .asoundrc = No sound

Tags: firefox, alsa

Here's the problem:

Manjaro Xfce/3.15.4, Alsa (No Pulse), Firefox 30 and 31, Gmusicbrowser, mplayer/smplayer

1. Firefox with youtube html5 player - no problems
2. Firefox with youtube html5 player and a basic .asoundrc - no audio
3. Firefox with standard flash player no problems
4. All other applications work with .asoundrc

I've tried various settings in .asoundrc, this is the current version.

```
pcm.!default {
type hw
card 0
device 0
}

ctl.!default {
type hw           
card 0
device 0
}
```

The reason I'm using the .asoundrc is to stop alsa resampling my 96000 tracks to 48000 and it works correctly.

```
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 0: ALC889 Analog [ALC889 Analog]
Subdevices: 1/1     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 1: ALC889 Digital [ALC889 Digital]
Subdevices: 1/1     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Any ideas?

Edit: I should mention, it's not just youtube. I have no sound with firefox/html5/.asoundrc anywhere.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution? I am also running without any PulseAudio and get no sound with HTML5 videos

Answer (score 2):

Your `.asoundrc` disables all software mixing.

If you want to output everything at 96 kHz, replace it with something like this:

```
defaults.pcm.dmix.rate 96000
```

Comment: `.asoundrc` disabling the software mixing is a *very* good information. I removed the `~/.asoundrc` and did set the preferences (my problem was that the default sound card was not the correct one) in `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf` and now the sound works like a charm in firefox. Many many thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this and it works for me (where my card is card 0):

```
defaults.pcm.card 0
defaults.ctl.card 0
defaults.ctl.card 0
```

just add that to the top of your `.asoundrc` and restart firefox. The rest of the file does not actually need to be empty.

Comment: You save my night! Youtube+HTML5 work fine now with Firefox but soundcloud not. With Chrome soundcloud work with HTML5 :D